# Limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+n}$ and similar

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits

Examine wether following sequences have limits and if yes - find them.

- a)$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+n}$
- b)$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2k+n}$
- c)$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+n}(\frac{1}{3})^k$

a) is easy. $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2k+n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{2k+n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2\frac{k}{n}+1} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2x + 1} = \frac{\log(3)}{2}$
but how about b) and c)?

Comment: Nice job on (a)! For (b), if you split the sum into its odd and even terms, then each one should again be a Riemann sum for an integral—indeed, the same integral, with opposite signs. Alternatively, you can combine adjacent pairs of summands manually and bound the result from above.